# Quality calculation on a list of Rules in ACO

Tags: algorithm, ant-colony

Am trying to figure out how we do the Quality calculation on a list of Rules in this algorithm:

[image]

I understood how to calculate the Quality on a Single Rule, using this formula:

[image]

But when it comes to the case of a list of Rules, how do we find out the Quality of the list of Rules?

We will find the Quality of Rules one by one and sums it up?

---

**EDIT**

Based on [this paper](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/pubs/2012/3244/content.pdf), the Quality of the list of Rules is found using this formula:

[image]

So almost getting my query solved with this. But am having doubt regarding the numerator of it. I mean the `total examples` is the total number of rows in the validation set isn't it? And the `number of correct classification` means number of rows in the validation set that matches the Rules of our list? I mean those rows that matches the Rule Terms as well as the Rule's class value?